# Лагает Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: при создании нового модуля типа Android Library, при вводе названия модуля происходит следующее:
Каждое изменения названия модуля сопровождается подвисанием AS на пару секунд.

После каждого изменения названия курсор прыгает в обратную сторону (написал что-то - курсор прыгнул назад, убрал что-то - курсор прыгнул вперёд).
На скриншоте снизу я ввёл название модуля "test".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Comment: Если оно лагает только в процессе ввода названия и вы не вводите названия целыми днями по доглу службы - то может стоит это игнорировать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, возможно, но я создаю новые библиотеки довольно-таки часто

Comment: Вряд ли кто-то тут сможет что-то сказать. Наверное, лучше всего попробовать создать баг в баг-трекере студии.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо!